# RDLC Crystal Report Set Column Group Result Vertical

Tags: crystal-reports, rdlc

I can't find any help online with my problem maybe due to that I don't know the exact keywords to use but hear me out.

Here is the screen shot of my report format...

[image]

The actual report result appears like this...

[image]

The next item appears beside (right side) the first result. I want it to appear below instead like this...

[image]

How do I achieve this? Just comment any additional information that is needed.

BTW, I am using visual studio 2013 (Seems like it matters).

UPDATE:

This is the report format that I want to copy. The headers are not important just the body of the report. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: are you using cross tabs?

Comment: @Siva I am not familiar with that. I don't think I am. I'm just using the Report Wizard on visual studio

Comment: how many groups have you created? can you show the design?

Comment: @Siva you can see the groups on the screenshots on the lower part

Comment: If you use groups then your output will be as expected by you but since you are getting side by side I guess you may have used cross tab...

Comment: @Siva seems like what I'm doing is actually a matrix report as seen in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56877/Create-Matrix-Report-using-ReportViewer-in-ASP-NET but this is not what I want.

Comment: It is very diffuclt to tell using just design on what you have done and what to be done... need some sample data so that atlease we can suggest or give you a hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what's wrong. I removed the column groupings and added only a parent row group. Then I added all needed rows and columns inside the group. It was fairly easy once I found out the problem.

Here's the output of my report.

Thanks guys!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use grouping go to this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ea36c5/crystal-reports-grouping-pattern-1/) hope this gives you a clue thanks

Comment: I've checked that one before but I am using Visual Studio 2013 and it's a bit different than the one on that tutorial. Can't seem to find out why it's adding new records horizontally..

Comment: can i see the output of the report ?

Comment: it's pretty much the same with what I posted but the difference is the actual data is show.

Comment: make sure that you put this parameters in "DETAILS SECTION"